# CrUX bug? Since multiple months CrUX displays other data as Lighthouse test

Tags: pagespeed-insights

In my understanding, CrUX data is an average of last 28 days, where the Lighthouse test is a live test result in a controlled environment. So how can it be, that CrUX displays since multiple 28-day timeframes other results, as Lighthouse displays in the same long time?

You can see the data discrepancy on the screenshot below. These data, both of CrUX and of Lighthouse, is same in a timeframe of five months: CrUX CLS is red, Lighthouse CLS is green.

How can it be? Is it a CrUX bug, or do I misunderstand/misinterpret displayed results?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Saw this also on the [CrUX mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chrome-ux-report/c/zqfscfw4ynA/m/bNN52vFWAAAJ) so posting same answer I gave there, here.

This suggests one of two things:

1. A different page is causing the CLS than the oost being tested. Note that PSI is only able to provide Origin-level CLS and not specific data for this URL:

[image: Close up of the top right of the above PSI screenshot]

or

2. Your shifts are caused post-load, rather than from the load that Lighthouse can check. This could be due to scrolling causing CLS (e.g. lazy loaded images without dimensions) or CLS that happens due to an interaction but after the 500ms grace period. CrUX measures CLS across the whole page life cycle from real users.

Both of these issues are discussed in the Optimize CLS guide: https://web.dev/articles/optimize-cls#understanding_where_your_shifts_are_coming_from

Comment: Search Console displays multiple URLs with CLS issue - but while testing each listed URLs with PageSpeed Insights the data on the URL level isn't available, everwhere only origin.

Comment: Search Console aggregates URLs into page groups (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9205520?hl=en#page_groups) and gives example URLs in each group. However, like the larger origin "grouping" that can still result in the example URLs having different characteristics (for better or worse) than the overall group-level aggregation. And if there is no page-level data then this can be difficult to see.

Comment: But it could well be post-load issues not seen by LightHouse. I would suggest using the Web Vitals extension with debugging enabled (https://web.dev/articles/debug-cwvs-with-web-vitals-extension) and trying some common user interactions (scroll, open/close menus, click on interactive widgets...etc.) to try to find any post-load CLS issues.